# Add row dynamically in reactive from

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I want to add the row dynamically which will contain a total of two or more rows in the HTML table

[image: Html table]

Whenever there are two rows or more rows in the form array another row should be added with the total.

This HTML table is dynamically generating the rows using ngFor over the array of objects.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a **table row** after the **ngFor** and add **ngIf** to check if the **number of objects** in the array is **greater than or equal to 2** (To show the total)

Your **html code** will look like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let object of objects">
   <td> {{object.field1}} </td>
   <td> {{object.field2}} </td>
   <td> {{object.field3}} </td>
   <td> {{object.field4}} </td>
</tr>
<tr *ngIf="showTotal()">
   <td>Total</td>
   <td>...</td>
   <td>...</td>
   <td>...</td>
   <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

And in your **.ts file**:

```
showTotal(): boolean {
    return this.objects.length >= 2;
}
```

The row containing the total will be created only if **the number of rows** in the table (which is the number of objects) **is greater than or equal to 2**)

Comment: and when to add those totals for each td.